# Optimal way to serve/store static files to be served by multiple nginx (docker) containers

Tags: docker, nginx, devops

For my web application I shall be using multiple nginx containers distributed over multiple physical hosts. However, I am not clear about the approach to be used to store and serve static files. Should I make a copy of all the static files on every physical host or there is some other better/more efficient option?

Comment: Bind or mount the static files, and ensure all hosts are members of the same stack.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the kind of content you're serving.

If you're always serving all or almost all the content (unlikely unless it's just some sort of static page), then you do need a copy of the content in each node for high performance.

However, if you're serving some of the content really often, and the rest not so often, which is more common (for example, a website with a deep hierarchy where some pages have the highest amount of visits and others are hardly ever visited), then you can configure your containers as reverse proxies with cache (see [nginx - reverse proxy with caching](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/reverseproxycachingexample/) for an example), and setup in a second layer some nginx containers that can serve all the static content.

This way, you can have a high, cheap amount of containers for load balancing and caching, and when there is a cache miss, they will query the more costful hosts that serve all the static content. This reduces storage costs with a good performance balance.

Alternative approaches include having containers serving a certain route (for example /home would be one container, /about-us another container, /services another container, etc), and an nginx entry point that would proxy the requests to the other containers. This one is good if you know beforehand how much traffic will go through each location.

Another option depends really on your network configuration. If all of your containers are in the same network, you can have a network storage with the static content, and bind the container volumes to such storage. Here you also want some sort of caching for performance reasons and to avoid collapsing the network with unneeded requests.

And finally, you can creatively combine all this options to give the most efficient structure to your network. You know the kind of site you're hosting, so you should be able to use this tools in a way that the content will be efficiently served. It's not the same to serve a static website with lightweight content, than serving lots of large files.

Comment: Thanks @marc-sances  for your elaborate reply. It really helped!